# My residence permit expires before my one-year Type D visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a national type D Greece visa that expires in October. My residence permit will expire in August. Since my visa is still valid, can I live in Greece after my residence permit expired but leave before the expiry of my visa?

Comment: How come that you have a D type visa and a residence permit?

Comment: @Neusser That's normal. Everyone who gets a visa to travel to EU countries for residence  (work, students, etc.) gets a type D visa and is expected to then obtain a residence permit after arriving.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is not normal that the residence permit expires earlier than D Visa which is given for 90 days.

Comment: @Neusser Yes, that part is not normal.